# Java - If statement not catching when variable equals string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

**(This may be a duplicate, I was not aware of `.equals`.  My apologies.)**

I was messing around in Java today when I decided to make a 4 character string generator.  I have the program generate every possible combination of characters that I defined.  This isn't for a project, I just wanted to see if this was possible.  My problem lies with the string checking.  I'll post the code first.

```
String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
String name = "Mike";
String pass;

outerLoop:
for (int a = 0; a < chars.length; a ++) {
    for (int b = 26; b < chars.length; b++) {
        for (int c = 26; c < chars.length; c++) {
            for (int d = 26; d < chars.length; d++) {
                pass = chars[a]+""+chars[b]+""+chars[c]+""+chars[d];
                System.out.println(pass);
                if (pass == name){
                    System.out.print("password");
                    break outerLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The nested `if` will check if `pass` is equal to Mike.  If it is, then it prints password and will break the for loop.

- Is `pass = chars[a]...` the correct way to do this?  When I tested it without the `if`, I had it print out pass and it printed all of the combinations correctly.  It did print `Mike`, but it did not catch in the `if`.
- I also changed the nested `for` loops so they start with the lower case because the program was taking a while to run when I made minor changes.

Comment: ...we really need to make asking this question against the rules of SO. It's... everywhere!

Comment: I apologise for the duplicate, I was not aware of `.equals()` and I didn't find it online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
            if (pass == name){
```

should be

```
            if (pass.equals(name)){
```

use [**String.equals()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check string equality. `==` operator simply checks if two reference variables refer to the same object. **equals()** method checks if two strings are meaningfully equal.

Comment: Congratulations on 8888 rep :)

Comment: I feel really silly for such a simple solution.  My professor did not catch this either when I asked him about it before I posted.

Comment: @MichaelGarrison i don't think your professor would have not known it. he might have just left for you to figure it out so that you wouldn't do the same mistake later :) anyways, now you know how to check string equality.and also do read out about to objects are compared in java . :)

Comment: wow +1 for this. spent an hour trying to figure this out. Why does Java do this when most languages don't? I guess I expected cross-language compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be compared using equals()

Comment: Really? I need to speak to my Professor then.  I asked him to take a look at this before I posted it here.

Comment: Your "professor" wouldn't last one minute in a job interview with me.

Comment: if somebody takes a look, that does not mean that he can see all errors.

Answer (score 0):

This comes up at least once per day. There should be a "close question" option dedicated to it. Nevertheless, here goes again...

The `==` operator tests if the two operands are the *same instance*.

The `.equals()` method compares the *values* of the two operands, but only if the class has implemented this method (which `String` does), otherwise it behaves the same as `==` (which is how the `Object` class implements it).